# Which convention should I adopt for functions that add columns to DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

Given the following DataFrame,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [3, 5, 7, 9],
    'b': [4, 12, 24, 40]
})
```

I would like to perform a number of steps that each add columns to this DataFrame. To keep things clean, I'd like to provide one function for each column-adding task. I can think of at least three ways to do it. What are the pros and cons of each approach?

### Method 1:

Create a Series with `apply()` and add it to the DataFrame as a new column:

```
def method1(row):
    return np.sqrt(row['a']**2 + row['b']**2)

# This is the line that will appear in main()
df['c'] = df.apply(method1, axis=1)
```

**Pros:**

- Clear in calling signature that a column is being added
- Good for parallelization

**Cons:**

- Does not permit multiple columns to be added by the function

### Method 2:

Pass the entire DataFrame into the function

```
def method2(df):
    df['c'] = np.sqrt(df['a']**2 + df['b']**2)

method2(df)
```

**Pros:**

- Less typing
- Avoids the behavior of `apply` that runs the function twice for the first row (only minor concern)

**Cons:**

- Less amenable to parallelization
- "In-place" operation (without explicit request) inconsistent with pandas convention, and the effect of function on `df` is obscure in `main()`

### Method 3:

Reconstruct DataFrame from lengthened rows with `apply()`

```
def method3(row):
    row['c'] = np.sqrt(row['a']**2 + row['b']**2)
    return row

df = df.apply(method3, axis=1)
```

**Pros:**

- Permits multiple columns to be added by single function
- Good for parallelization

**Cons:**

- The fact that columns are added is not clear in the call signature
- Performance (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misunderstanding here is that `apply` parallelizes operations... *it doesn't*.

All it is, is wrapper around a loop. It works something like this:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(method1, axis=1)
```

Is equivalent to,

```
temp = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    temp.append(method1(row))

df['c'] = temp
```

On the other hand, just doing

```
df['c'] = (df['a'] ** 2 + df['b'] ** 2) ** .5
```

Implicitly vectorizes the entire operation. This is because numpy has many of its basic routines implemented in C, and uses SIMD operations, making this faster than a traditional loop. Time this versus the version with `apply` and you understand.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)  

%timeit df.apply(method1, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 19.1 s per loop

%timeit (df['a'] ** 2 + df['b'] ** 2) ** .5
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

The rule of thumb is to always avoid loopy/loop-like solutions, unless your operations are so complex that they cannot be avoided. In that situation, use a simple *for* loop, the overhead actually works out to be less than `apply`. You'll thank yourself for it.

Answer (score 0):

My preference in order of priority:

1. **Method 2**: This is vectorised and optimal for most datasets. Remember that under the hood `pandas` uses `numpy`, so performing vectorised calculations with `np.sqrt` is efficient.
2. **Method 1**: `df.apply` is not vectorised. It's a thinly veiled loop. Yes, you can optimise the loop with tools such as `numba` or `cython`, but then you might as well hold your data and do all your calculations in `numpy` and produce your `pd.DataFrame` for purely aesthetic reasons once your calculations are completed.
3. **Method 3**: Opaque and unnecessary use of `df.apply`. You would never choose this method ahead of Method 1, therefore it comes last.